# Angular change input signal value from within component

Tags: angular, angular-signals

I am new to signals in angular and i want to change my input signal from within component

```
selected = input(false);
```

I would except to do somethin like this

```
this.selected().set(true)
this.selected.set(true)
```

But that doesn't seem to work. What am i missing :)

Comment: try `this.selected.set(true)`

Comment: @NarenMurali Doesnt work either type is InputSignal<boolean, boolean>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As of Angular 17.2.0-next.1:**

Input signals are read-only inside the component that receives them.you can't change the input signal directly. you have to use a computed property to calculate a new value based on it.

```
_select = signal(false);
hasSelected = computed(() => this.selected() || this._select());
```

**[Input Signal RFC](https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682#:%7E:text=two%2Dway%20bindings%3F-,Inputs%20are%20read%2Donly,-In%20signal%2Dbased)**

**Update:**

In Angular **17.2.0-rc.1** release, we can use the model input feature. This feature enables model() to return a writable signal that implicitly defines an input/output pair. This pair can be used either in two-way bindings to keep two values in sync or by binding individually to the input and output.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'counter',
  standalone: true,
  host: {
    '(click)': 'increment()',
  }
})
export class Counter {
  value = model(0);

  increment(): void {
    this.value.update(current => current + 1);
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `<counter [(value)]="count"/> The current count is: {{count()}}`,
})
class App {
  count = signal(0);
}
```

[Initial implementation PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/54252)

Comment: this gives an example of how to solve my problem although first answer is better in terms of information.

Comment: @DživoJelić Updated with few more information. please check

Comment: thx that is what i am really looking forward to in the next releases :)

Comment: @DživoJelić model input feature available in angular latest release

Answer (score 3):

In the docs these is the details for input signal!

#### [InputSignal](https://angular.io/api/core/InputSignal)

> InputSignal is represents a special Signal for a directive/component input.

---

> An input signal is similar to a **non-writable signal** except that it also carries additional type-information for transforms, and that Angular internally updates the signal whenever a new value is bound.

SO this type of signal is only meant as a alternative for `@Input` of angular, but its special because it also has the power to throw an error when no input is provided, when you configure it as `selected = input.required` so it can be used to mandate passing input properties!

**Since the signal is non-writable we cannot set the value, we can only accept values coming from the parent element!**